# Disabling Parallelization For Systemd, For Cpu Overclocking

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to discover a way to alter the systemd
initialization process to disable the parallelization
of processes' to enable overclocking my cpu
without crashing the system on startup.

My system is explicitly a gaming system, with basic
built in overclocking controls in the bios, and I
research all the ways to tweak linux systems,
at this time debian, to get maximum performance
out of them for general usage as well as gaming.

Currently, this is the major bottleneck I have discovered,
whereas many alterations for improving performance are very
straightforward/simple to implement. Altering the function
of systemd is apparently more complex.

I can't see anyway of simply achieving this goal without
manually editing the systemd unit configuration files,
which is a little intimidating as opposed to a simple
option or switch built in for this specific utility.

There might be another solution to this problem I can't
think of, but it seems obvious that the parallelization
of startup processes creates the conditions that
cause my system to crash while I turn on cpu overclocking in bios.

I tried other distro's with alternate init systems like
openrc, and runit, and that could be a solution, but
ideally there should be a solution for systemd which
a lot of applications are dependent on.

From the debian manual..
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html

```
3.2. Systemd init

This section describes how system is started by the systemd(1) program with PID=1 (i.e., init process).

The systemd init process spawns processes in parallel based on the unit configuration files (see systemd.unit(5)) which are written in declarative style instead of SysV-like procedural style.

The spawned processes are placed in individual Linux control groups named after the unit which they belong to in the private systemd hierarchy (see cgroups and Section 4.7.4, “Linux security features”).

The unit configuration files are loaded from a set of paths (see systemd-system.conf(5)) as follows:

    "/lib/systemd/system": OS default configuration files

    "/etc/systemd/system": system administrator configuration files which override the OS default configuration files

    "/run/systemd/system": run-time generated configuration files which override the installed configuration files

Their inter-dependencies are specified by the directives "Wants=", "Requires=", "Before=", "After=", … (see "MAPPING OF UNIT PROPERTIES TO THEIR INVERSES" in systemd.unit(5)). The resource controls are also defined (see systemd.resource-control(5)).

The suffix of the unit configuration file encodes their types as:

    *.service describes the process controlled and supervised by systemd. See systemd.service(5).

    *.device describes the device exposed in the sysfs(5) as udev(7) device tree. See systemd.device(5).

    *.mount describes the file system mount point controlled and supervised by systemd. See systemd.mount(5).

    *.automount describes the file system auto mount point controlled and supervised by systemd. See systemd.automount(5).

    *.swap describes the swap device or file controlled and supervised by systemd. See systemd.swap(5).

    *.path describes the path monitored by systemd for path-based activation. See systemd.path(5).

    *.socket describes the socket controlled and supervised by systemd for socket-based activation. See systemd.socket(5).

    *.timer describes the timer controlled and supervised by systemd for timer-based activation. See systemd.timer(5).

    *.slice manages resources with the cgroups(7). See systemd.slice(5).

    *.scope is created programmatically using the bus interfaces of systemd to manages a set of system processes. See systemd.scope(5).

    *.target groups other unit configuration files to create the synchronization point during start-up. See systemd.target(5).

Upon system start up (i.e., init), the systemd process tries to start the "/lib/systemd/system/default.target (normally symlinked to "graphical.target"). First, some special target units (see systemd.special(7)) such as "local-fs.target", "swap.target" and "cryptsetup.target" are pulled in to mount the filesystems. Then, other target units are also pulled in by the target unit dependencies. For details, read bootup(7).

systemd offers backward compatibility features. SysV-style boot scripts in "/etc/init.d/rc[0123456S].d/[KS]name" are still parsed and telinit(8) is translated into systemd unit activation requests.
```

and the /etc/systemd/system.conf

```
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the system.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/system.conf' to display the full conf>
#
# See systemd-system.conf(5) for details.

[Manager]
#LogLevel=info
#LogTarget=journal-or-kmsg
#LogColor=yes
#LogLocation=no
#LogTime=no
#DumpCore=yes
#ShowStatus=yes
#CrashChangeVT=no
#CrashShell=no
#CrashReboot=no
#CtrlAltDelBurstAction=reboot-force
#CPUAffinity=
#NUMAPolicy=default
#NUMAMask=
#RuntimeWatchdogSec=off
#RuntimeWatchdogPreSec=off
#RuntimeWatchdogPreGovernor=
#RebootWatchdogSec=10min
#KExecWatchdogSec=off
#WatchdogDevice=
#CapabilityBoundingSet=
#NoNewPrivileges=no
#SystemCallArchitectures=
#TimerSlackNSec=
#StatusUnitFormat=description
#DefaultTimerAccuracySec=1min
#DefaultStandardOutput=journal
#DefaultStandardError=inherit
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutAbortSec=
#DefaultDeviceTimeoutSec=90s
#DefaultRestartSec=100ms
#DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec=10s
#DefaultStartLimitBurst=5
#DefaultEnvironment=
#DefaultCPUAccounting=no
#DefaultIOAccounting=no
#DefaultIPAccounting=no
#DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes
#DefaultTasksAccounting=yes
#DefaultTasksMax=15%
#DefaultLimitCPU=
#DefaultLimitFSIZE=
#DefaultLimitDATA=
#DefaultLimitSTACK=
#DefaultLimitCORE=
#DefaultLimitRSS=
#DefaultLimitNOFILE=1024:524288
#DefaultLimitAS=
#DefaultLimitNPROC=
#DefaultLimitMEMLOCK=8M
#DefaultLimitLOCKS=
#DefaultLimitSIGPENDING=
#DefaultLimitMSGQUEUE=
#DefaultLimitNICE=
#DefaultLimitRTPRIO=
#DefaultLimitRTTIME=
#DefaultOOMPolicy=stop
#DefaultSmackProcessLabel=
```

the man page for systemd points out...

```
6. Automount units provide automount capabilities, for on-demand
   mounting of file systems as well as parallelized boot-up. See
   systemd.automount(5).
```

Comment: I don't believe your OC amounts to more than 5% of performance, so to me you're wasting your time and talent instead of e.g. replacing your entire PC.

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is unstable running multiple tasks in parallel, then it will not be able to run modern games, which also run multiple tasks in parallel.

For example it is now common to split graphics processing between a tighter loop operating on geometry data (so you get position updates every frame) and a slower loop updating the lighting (nobody notices if a light flickers differently), and then run both in parallel.

When overclocking, you need to select a configuration that remains stable at full load over hours even as components heat up an tolerances shrink.

Comment: The problem is during the init process, and enabling multi-core enhancement which means running the cores at the highest speed at the same time. I tried all the different configuration options for the power state upon startup: max battery, max non-turbo, and turbo boost. I tried all the configuration options for general overclocking, like intel speedstep, and intel speedshift. The specific problem is using the multicore enhancement which depending on the power options causes a kernel panic or hardware time sync errors which crash the startup process or stall it completely.

Answer (score 0):

So it doesn't even matter a little default applet controls it from within the operating system on xfce panel. now I'm blazing fast

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please note that SE communities are not discussion forums. rules are a bit different. Answers are reserved only for answering questions, not commenting, Please check the Help section to learn how things work. Once you have gained enough reputation you can start commenting on other postings. Until then, I'd advise you to delete this - this kind of "answers" get downvoted, which removes reputation points, and flagged as "low quality", which may lead into not being able to post answers.